# Flutter BLoC pattern Future<T>.then is not triggers base on repository network results

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm new to Flutter and BLoC pattern. I have implemented a simple get network call using the BLoC pattern.
Flowing repository calls get hotel method base on the input parameter provided to the network call.

```
class HotelSearchRepository {
  
  Future<Resource<List<Hotel>>> getHotelSearchResults(
      HashMap<String, Object> requestData) async {

    try {

      final response = await Network().getHotelSearchResults(requestData);
      final data  = HotelResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data));

      if (data.status) {
        final hotels = data.hotelsArray.hotels;
        final hotelSearchData = List<Hotel>();

        hotels.forEach((hotel) {
          final hotelImage = hotel.hotelImage;
          final hotelTripAdvisorRatingUrl = hotel.hotelTripAdvisorRatingUrl;
          final promoDescription = hotel.promoDescription;
          final hotelName = hotel.hotelName;
          final hotelAddress = hotel.hotelAddress1;
          final hotelRatings = hotel.hotelStar;
          final isBeadInBreakfirstAvaiable =
              hotel.hotelBoardBasis != null && hotel.hotelBoardBasis == "BB";
          final extraperks = hotel.hotelRoom;
          final oldPrice = hotel.hotelBaserate;
          final currentPrice = hotel.hotelPrice;

          var currencyNumberFormatter = NumberFormat.currency(
              locale: "si", customPattern: "###,###,###,###");

          final hotelItem = Hotel(
              name: hotelName,
              address: hotelAddress,
              rating: double.parse(hotelRatings),
              image: hotelImage,
              tripAdviserImageLink: hotelTripAdvisorRatingUrl,
              promotionDescription: promoDescription,
              isBeadInBreakfirstAvaiable: isBeadInBreakfirstAvaiable,
              extraperks: extraperks,
              oldPrice: currencyNumberFormatter.format(oldPrice),
              currentPrice: currencyNumberFormatter.format(currentPrice));

          hotelSearchData.add(hotelItem);
        });

        return Resource(DataRetrieveStatus.SUCCESS, hotelSearchData);

      } else {

        var displayMessage = DisplayMessage(
            title: "Response Error", description: data.errorMessage);
            
        return Resource.displayConstructor(
            DataRetrieveStatus.RESPONSE_ERROR, displayMessage);

      }

    } on DioError catch (e) {

      switch (e.type) {
        case DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT:
        case DioErrorType.SEND_TIMEOUT:
        case DioErrorType.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT:
        case DioErrorType.RESPONSE:

        var displayMessage = DisplayMessage(
              title: "Connection Error",description:  "Application fiald top connect with the server");

          return Resource.displayConstructor(
              DataRetrieveStatus.CONNECTION_ERROR, displayMessage);

          break;
        case DioErrorType.DEFAULT:

          var displayMessage = DisplayMessage(
              title: "Processing Error", description:"Something went wrong. Please try again later.");

          return Resource.displayConstructor(
              DataRetrieveStatus.PROCESSING_ERROR, displayMessage);

          break;
        case DioErrorType.CANCEL:
          break;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Stetho to monitor network calls and I'm getting the result with status been false. I placed a Debugging point to make sure it hits the return statement. Although it calls `return Resource.displayConstructor(DataRetrieveStatus.RESPONSE_ERROR, displayMessage);` Line code in my `DataretrieveBloc` do not triggers.

```
class DataretrieveBloc extends Bloc<DataretrieveEvent, DataretrieveState> {
  final HotelSearchRepository hotelSearchRipository;

  DataretrieveBloc(this.hotelSearchRipository);

  @override
  DataretrieveState get initialState => DataretrieveInitial();

  @override
  Stream<DataretrieveState> mapEventToState(DataretrieveEvent event) async* {
    yield HotelLoading();

    if (event is GetHotels) {
      HashMap<String, Object> requestData = HashMap();
      requestData["check_in"] = event.checkInDate;
      requestData["check_out"] = event.checkOutDate;
      requestData["city_full_str"] = event.city;
      requestData["sgen"] = event.sgen;
      requestData["page"] = event.page;

      final hotelSearchResults =
          hotelSearchRipository.getHotelSearchResults(requestData);

      hotelSearchResults.then((resource) async* {

        var status = resource.status;

        switch (status) {
          case DataRetrieveStatus.SUCCESS:
            yield HotelSearchData(resource.data);
            break;
          case DataRetrieveStatus.RESPONSE_ERROR:
          case DataRetrieveStatus.CONNECTION_ERROR:
          case DataRetrieveStatus.PROCESSING_ERROR:
            yield HotelSearchError(resource.displayMessage);
            break;
        }

      });
    }
  }
}
```

I've test by placing a debug point inside `hotelSearchResults.then((resource) async* {}` statement but it never triggers.Is there an error in my code? Any help to spot the error in my code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `yield` adds an object to the `Iterable` (sync*) or `Stream` (async*) associated with the **immediately** enclosing function.

Rewrite your code with `await` for `getHotelSearchResults()` and  `yield` new states only in scope of `mapEventToState()` function

```
Stream<DataretrieveState> mapEventToState(DataretrieveEvent event) async* {
  // this part of code is in lexical scope of mapEventToState()
  final resource = await hotelSearchRipository.getHotelSearchResults(requestData);

  var status = resource.status;

  switch (status) {
    case DataRetrieveStatus.SUCCESS:
      yield HotelSearchData(resource.data);
      break;
    case DataRetrieveStatus.RESPONSE_ERROR:
    case DataRetrieveStatus.CONNECTION_ERROR:
    case DataRetrieveStatus.PROCESSING_ERROR:
      yield HotelSearchError(resource.displayMessage);
      break;
  }
} // end of mapEvent
```

**Where is the problem?**

```
futureFoo.then((resource) async* { yield SomeObject();});
```

1. new `Stream` returned by anonymous function marked as `async*` generator
2. you `yield` items to this `Stream`
3. but nobody listen to this stream

I insist that you read the documentation about [generators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators)